# How To Have Modular EF Context in Different Projects in Bit-Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, bit-framework

I have many projects in a solution that use bit-framework. When I use many contexts in different projects, I have just last Repository of the last Module.

```
    public IEnumerable<IAppModule> GetAppModules()
    {  
        yield return this;
        yield return new ModuleA();
        yield return new ModuleB();
       ...
    }

    public virtual void ConfigureDependencies(IServiceCollection services,IDependencyManager dependencyManager)
    {
AssemblyContainer.Current.AddAppAssemblies(typeof(ModuleA).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);


AssemblyContainer.Current.AddAppAssemblies(typeof(ModuleB).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
       ...
       }
```

In ModuleA AppModule:

```
dependencyManager.RegisterEfCoreDbContext<ModuleAContext, SqlServerDbContextObjectsProvider>();
```

In ModuleB AppModule:

```
dependencyManager.RegisterEfCoreDbContext<ModuleBContext, SqlServerDbContextObjectsProvider>();
```